# What will happen if I feed this rangefinder 3.3v?

Tags: voltage-regulator, msp430

I have this rangefinder http://www.hobbyengineering.com/H2951.html and my MCU is running on 3.3v (MSP430G2231), will this thing work poorly if I feed it 3.3v instead of 5v? I really don't want to have TWO voltage regulators on this board. If not what else can I do to get it the voltage it needs? The power source is a 9.6v battery pack with a LD33V - 3.3V regulator.

Spec sheet:
http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/PingDocs.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems with two regulators. You really aren't putting the two in parallel. Both inputs will be connected to the voltage source and the differnt voltage outputs will go to the different sections of the circuit. (You still need your input and output caps). I do this quite frequently with 12V and 5V regulators without any problems.

I didn't see a minimum trigger voltage spec for the TTL trigger pulse going to the range finder so you'll need to ensure that it will recognise the signals from your 3V MCU as high.

At the worst, you would need a logic level converter like [this one](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745) from Sparkfun.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you. Do you know if the converter would work with PWM?

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely to work very well unless you feed it with 5V. Just add a 5V regulator to your board. MSP430 inputs aren't 5V-compatible, IIRC; a 1k series resistor might be all that you need to avoid damage.

Comment: anything I should worry about with having two voltage regulators in parallel?

Comment: They aren't in parallel. You only have the inputs connected to the same supply.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to put the regulators in series.  A rangefinder and MSP430 are both going to be very low-power, but when you're regulating from 9.6V, 12V, or more, it's usually cheaper to put one heavy-duty regulator at your highest voltage, and then run your lower voltage regulators off of that.

Usually, you can get away with heatsinking just the pre-regulator in this situation, instead of heatsinking two independent regulators.  You'll just have to make sure that you have sufficient capacitance that you don't get any oscillation from their interaction.